# Terminate alarm task when the app is terminated via Task Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I create an alarm to retrieve location every 30 seconds, as follows:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "requesting location tracking.");

        // start the service
        Intent tracking = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateManager.class);
        context.startService(tracking);
    }
}
```

Here is the call from MainActivity to start the location update

```
private void startTracking(Context context) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "startTracking()");

    // get a Calendar object with current time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, START_DELAY);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    trackingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), UPDATE_INTERVAL, trackingIntent);
}
```

And here is the call to stop the location update:

```
public void stopTracking() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "stopTracking()");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    trackingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.cancel(trackingIntent);
}
```

In this application, whenever the app is terminated (by any means) I would like to stop the alarm also (i.e. stop updating location). To this end, I call stopTracking() in onDestroy():

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy()");

    stopTracking();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I have tested many times on Samsung Galaxy S4 - 4.4.2: I open the app, put it in background (by pressing home button), then open task manager and clear the app from memory. Several times the alarm stops, but several times the alarm is still alive. Could someone explain for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use application class for that.Application's class instance will be available until when app isn't closed or killed(not minimised).When app get killed onTerminate of this class will be called.See below code.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();

    //do your code here.
}

}
```

don't forget to add this instance to AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
   <application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
   </application>
```

But as suggested by @waqaslam, you should not rely on this because there is no gaurantee that it will be called in Real device [Reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29).

One more and better thing that before user kills app from "recent apps" screen or from task manager , onPause() of running activities will be always called. So you need to save all data or do finalize work in onPause() method.That would be better.Hope it will help.Thanks.

Comment: One should never rely on `onTerminate`. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29).